# How to get the latest data point in each month in each year?

Tags: mysql, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is an example snippet of my dataset.
I have multiple data points for each month in each year , over a number of years.
I want to get the latest row in each month in each year

Ex:

```
     data       value
   2019-01-1     10
   2019-01-7     20
   2019-01-28    30
                 
   2019-03-4     50
   2019-03-17    40 
   2019-03-28    20

   2020-04-16    80 
   2020-04-18    60
   2020-04-30    40

   2020-05-16    90 
   2020-05-18    10
   2020-05-30    80
```

Expected output

```
data         value
2019-01-28    30
2019-03-28    20
2020-04-30    40
2020-05-30    80
```

I would like to achieve this with flask-sqlalchemy.
I'm thinking I'll have to group by month maybe? I'm quite new to sql queries. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit : I've tried this :

```
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM date),
EXTRACT(month FROM date)
```

but this gives me the first row of each month , I want the last row, i.e the latest row

Comment: *I'll have to group by month maybe?* By year and month.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this  `GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM date),
EXTRACT(month FROM date) HAVING MAX(date) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)` but I'm not able to get the last row of the month(Which is the required row). I'm getting the first row of the month.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for MySQL.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table AS t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(data) AS data
       FROM table t2
       GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y%m') ) t3 USING (data)
```

The query assimes that `data` column have no duplicates (is defined as UNIQUE).

---

GROUP BY expression may be `GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM data), EXTRACT(month FROM data)` as you have tried... or even `GROUP BY data DIV 100`. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(data), month(data) order by data desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.data = (select max(t2.data)
                from t t2
                where year(t2.data) = year(t.data) and
                      month(t2.data) = month(t.data)
               );
```

Often, the correlated subquery performs better.  In this case, though, it cannot (easily) be optimized using indexes, so I suspect that window functions are faster.